# T-network feedback of opamp

Tags: operational-amplifier, inverting-amplifier

[image: Picture 1]

How are the output (Vo) and H(s) = Vo/Vin calculated in this schematic?

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do it to replace the T-network with a single resistor.

How to do it can be found here:

[Op-amp with T network in the feedback path](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/333055/op-amp-with-t-network-in-the-feedback-path)

$$R_F = R_5 + R_6 + \frac{R_5 R_6}{R_7}$$
After doing all the simplification (C2 and C3 are connected in series, the R3 and R4 as well).

We end up with this equivalent circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftzd8M.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And full analysis of this circuit can be found for example here:

[Gain of filter is higher than calculated - why?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/179356/gain-of-filter-is-higher-than-calculated-why/316935#316935)

[How does this filter work?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/338421/how-does-this-filter-work)

[Deriving Bandpass Transfer Function](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/351811/deriving-bandpass-transfer-function/351812#351812)

For example, the max gain will be equal to

$$A_{\text{max}}=\frac{R_FC_3}{R_FC_4+R_3C_3} \approx 55.54 \:[V/V] = 34.9dB $$

Answer (score 2):

## The meaningless "T"

A circuit can be represented and named in different ways, but it is good that it has some meaning.

### T-network

"T-network" is an example of a meaningless name that does nothing to help its understanding. It is a way of drawing (grouping of elements) that resembles the letter "T" and that is it. It says nothing about the circuit's function.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fb7MHi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

### Loaded voltage divider

If we look carefully at the circuit diagram, we will notice that the two resistors on the right (R1 and R2) form a *voltage divider*, and the left resistor (R) is grounded, and can be considered as a load of the voltage divider. So the "T- network" is actually a *loaded voltage divider*. Usually its output resistance is much lower than that of the load so its gain is approximately R2/(R1 + R2). In the schematic below, I have adjusted (slightly increased) R2 so that the gain is exactly 1/10.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDkdy2.png)</sup>

## Building the circuit

Many times I have had to explain this clever circuit trick, but now I will do it in a more different way - based on it, I will formulate a more general *principle of virtual resistance modification*. I will do it as usual in several successive steps.

### Real resistance

Let's take a 100 kΩ resistor but pretend we don't know its resistance and decide to measure it experimentally. For this purpose, we supply it with a 1 V voltage source Vs and measure the current I through it. As you can see, the resistance is the same - R = 1V/10μA = 100kΩ.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6Vhsm.png)</sup>

### Virtually increased resistance

Now let's apply the clever trick by reducing the voltage applied to the resistor R by a factor of 10. For this purpose, we insert an R1-R2 voltage divider between the supply voltage Vs and the resistor R. As above, we pretend not to notice the divider, and measure the resistance in the familiar way - R = 1V/1μA = 1 MΩ. However, what is our surprise when we see that it is 10 times higher!

The trick here is that we "do not see the divider" and use the previous 1 V voltage again... but the current is now 10 times smaller; so the resistance looks 10 times higher. Really clever trick!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSqKET.png)</sup>

### Virtually decreased resistance

And can't we (just out of curiosity) do the opposite - virtually reduce the resistance? Obviously, instead of a 1/10 attenuator we need to insert a 10 x amplifier (I have set the op-amp gain to 10 in the *parameters* window). As you can see from the gauge readings, both voltage and current increase 10 times, and the resistance "decreases" 10 times.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8H5B0.png)</sup>

### Op-amp 4-resistor circuit

Finally, let's make an op-amp circuit of an *inverting amplifier* where the resistor R2 is virtually "increased" 10 times by the help of the R3-R4 voltage divider. Here the op-amp is "fooled". It does not "see" the R1-R2 voltage divider and "thinks" that the resistance R2 = 1 MΩ. That is why it increases its output voltage 10 times.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7WexQ.png)</sup>

### Equivalent 2-resistor circuit

So the 4-resistor op-amp circuit above behaves as the classic 2-resistor inverting amplifier with R2 = 1 MΩ.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMjhQU.png)</sup>